# Valid Objects for a template argument

Tags: c++

Consider the following code :

```
  template <class T>
    T average(T *atArray, int nNumValues)
    {
        T tSum = 0;
        for (int nCount = 0; nCount < nNumValues; nCount++)
        {
            tSum += atArray[nCount];
        }
        tSum = tSum / nNumValues;
        return tSum;

}
```

And the following question on it :

Which of the following statements about the class/type T must be true in order for the code to compile and run without crashing?

1. It must be some kind of numeric type
2. Must have < operator-defined
3. Must have the [ ] access operator-defined
4. Must have copy constructor and assignment operator

**My Thoughts:** 
I think it could be something apart from numeric type but it will need to have the operator + and / well defined.

point 2 seems incorrect as < has no relation with / and + operator

same with point 3 and point 4.
Although I am not sure about my reasoning above.

Comment: Note that operator+ is not used in code; operator+= is.

Comment: If this is homework, it's polite to say so, or add the "homework" tag. That doesn't mean it's off topic here.

Comment: It depends on which generation of the C++ standard you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

1. No - It could for example do implicit conversions to/from a numeric type and have `operator+=` defined.
2. No - That operator is not used on a `T`
3. No - That operator is not used on a `T`, only a `T*` and pointer types all have this operator defined.
4. No - The copy constructor can be `delete`d and the question says "*and*" so the answer is *no*. It needs some kind of assignment operator though.

Consider this class, especially constructed to be able to answer *no* to as many questions as possible:

```
struct foo {
    foo() = default;
    foo(int) {}                                   // implicit conversion from int
    
    foo(const foo&) = delete;                     // no copy constructor
    foo(foo&&) = default;                         // but move constructor
    foo& operator=(const foo&) = delete;          // no copy assignment
    foo& operator=(foo&&) = delete;               // no move assignment
    
    foo& operator=(int) { return *this; };        // but assignment from int

    foo& operator+=(const foo&) { return *this; } // for tSum += atArray[nCount];

    operator int() const { return 1; }            // implicit conversion to int
};
```

And it would work fine with the function template:

```
int main() {
    foo arr[2];

    auto x = average(arr, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A class type with sufficient overloaded operators (like `std::complex<double>`) could work.
2. The `<` is only used on `int` expressions, not involving `T`.
3. The `atArray[nCount]` expression uses a `T*` pointer, not an expression with type `T`, so it has the built-in meaning.
4. Technically no, since fundamental types don't have constructors or assignment operators at all, just similar semantics. Also, technically every class type "has" a copy constructor and assignment operator, even if deleted. Another issue: `T` could be a class with normal assignment operator, deleted copy constructor, and public non-deleted move constructor.

Probably the intended answer is #4.

The actual requirements on `T` are:

1. A variable of type `T` can be copy-initialized from an `int`, or from a null pointer constant. (`0` is a special expression which can do two different things...)
2. `T` is a numeric type, or an enumeration or class type with valid operator functions supporting expressions:

   1. `a += b` and `a = b`, where `a` and `b` are lvalues of type `T`
   2. `a / n`, where `a` is an lvalue of type `T` and `n` is an lvalue of type `int`
3. `T` is move-constructible.